# cloning a class instance in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm 'simply' trying to clone an instance in typescript.

`jQuery.extend(true, {}, instance)`

doesn't work because methods are not copied

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Define clone an instance please. No one seems to agree on what it actually means even in languages where the concept is vaguely popular, like Java.

Comment: Anyway, try `Object.create(instance.prototype)`

Comment: @AluanHaddad thx for your quick reply, unfortunately this doesn't work with TS

Comment: Please see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create regardless, it has nothing to do with TypeScript. As in JavaScript so in TypeScript is critical to understand

Answer (score 21):

You can have a generic clone function if your classes have a default constructor:

```
function clone<T>(instance: T): T {
    const copy = new (instance.constructor as { new (): T })();
    Object.assign(copy, instance);
    return copy;
}
```

For example:

```
class A {
    private _num: number;
    private _str: string;

    get num() {
        return this._num;
    }

    set num(value: number) {
        this._num = value;
    }

    get str() {
        return this._str;
    }

    set str(value: string) {
        this._str = value;
    }
}

let a = new A();
a.num = 3;
a.str = "string";

let b = clone(a);
console.log(b.num); // 3
console.log(b.str); // "string"
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20clone%3CT%3E(instance%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20copy%20%3D%20new%20(instance.constructor%20as%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%20%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.assign(copy%2C%20instance)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20copy%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_num%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_str%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20num()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._num%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20num(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._num%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20str()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._str%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20str(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._str%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Aa.num%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0Aa.str%20%3D%20%22string%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20clone(a)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.num)%3B%20%2F%2F%203%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.str)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22string%22))

If your classes are more complicated (have other class instances as members and/or don't have a default constructor) then add a `clone` method in your classes which knows how to construct and assign values.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In that case I need to make sure I never use the constructor, instead I use factories and setters? cheers

Comment: Fine, then export a factory function and the clone function but don't export the class itself

Comment: @ValikhanAkhmedov Well, you can't have 'set' methods for fields that are 'readonly', that's the whole point.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@Nitzan Tomer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42737273/91403) I came up with the following code, that will automatically clone nested properties when they are `Cloneable`, however I am not fully aware of how profane this is and what shortcomings are present in this approach;

```
import { isUndefined } from "lodash";

export abstract class Cloneable<T> {
  clone(newPropertyValues: Partial<T> = {}): T {
    const clone = new (this.constructor as { new (): T })();

    const nestedClones = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clone)
      .reduce((partial, propertyName) => {
        const property = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(clone, propertyName) 
        const isCloneable = property?.value instanceof Cloneable
        const isNotProvided = isUndefined(
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newPropertyValues, propertyName)
        )
        
        if(isCloneable && isNotProvided) {
          partial[propertyName as keyof T] = property?.value.clone()
        }

        return partial
      }, {} as Partial<T>)

    return Object.assign(clone, this, nestedClones, newPropertyValues);
  }

  cloneWith(newPropertyValues: Partial<T>): T {
    return this.clone(newPropertyValues)
  } 
}
```

Now you just inherit from `Cloneable<T>` and then you can benefit from a `clone` method and a typed `cloneWith`* in case you want to override some values.

**`cloneWith` is provided just for enhanced semantics*